# Formatting CSV column width

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I want to format `CSV` file.

My requirement is to set the column width while exporting `CSV`. I am using `FASTER CSV` to generate `CSV` file.

Also I have one field which contains long sentences.when I export `CSV`, the `CSV` file doesn't show the value in the column directly.However if I click on the column field it shows the value.I want it to be displayed directly when `CSV` is opened.

I have searched a lot but not getting solution, Please help me.

Comment: Are you viewing these files in Excel? Do your long sentences contain punctuation (e.g. commas)? By column width do you mean displayed width in excel or length of data?

Comment: Any field which has long sentence or words cannot be diplayed.If i have a long title it won't be diplayed in csv.this problem occurs onlyin windows and doesn't occurs in Ubuntu.

Comment: A CSV does not contain a width. It contains values, separated by commas because a CSV is just Comma Separated Values. The displayed width is ENTIRELY decided by the application you use to display the CSV.

Comment: Thank you Mark. In windows 7 I am using Excel to open the CSV.Which application is more suitable?? can you suggest some??

Comment: MarkSetchell can you post your comment as the answer.

Comment: @Ajit I have done as you asked. I think Excel is already the most suitable application in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSV does not contain a width. It contains values, separated by commas because a CSV is just Comma Separated Values.

The displayed width is ENTIRELY decided by the application you use to display the CSV.